# Can't match class type with specific type in haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have the following situation in my code (simplified but semantically identical)

```
class Graph a where
    edges :: EdgeSet c => a -> c
```

I have many subtypes that fulfill the graph interface. One of them is a tree

```
data Tree = Tree

instance Graph Tree where
    edges tree = DirectedEdgeSet
```

A call on the edges method should return a `DirectedEdgeSet`. This should be OK since `DirectedEdgeSet` implements the `EdgeSet` class:

```
type Edge = (Int, Int)
data DirectedEdgeSet = DirectedEdgeSet (Set Edge) Int

class EdgeSet c where
    content :: c -> Set Edge
    size :: c -> Int

instance EdgeSet DirectedEdgeSet where
    content (DirectedEdgeSet es _) = es
    size (DirectedEdgeSet _ x) = x
```

This example does not compile:

```
   • Couldn't match expected type ‘c’
                  with actual type ‘DirectedEdgeSet’
      ‘c’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          edges :: forall c. EdgeSet c => Tree -> c
        at Tree.hs:10:5
    • In the expression: DirectedEdgeSet
      In an equation for ‘edges’: edges tree = DirectedEdgeSet
      In the instance declaration for ‘Graph Tree’
    • Relevant bindings include
        edges :: Tree -> c (bound at Tree.hs:10:5)
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the type of the class method; `edges :: EdgeSet c => a -> c` is a function which takes *any* `a` (constrained with `a` being an instance of `Graph`) and returns *any* `c` (constrained with `c` being an instance of `EdgeSet c`). You probably instead want to say it returns *some* `c` obeying the aforementioned constraint.

#### Haskell 98 solution

You could just require that edges return an actual `Set` (like the one from `Data.Set`) for all graphs:

```
class Graph a where
  edges :: a -> Data.Set Edge
```

#### `ExistentialQuantification` solution

Otherwise, you can use the `ExistentialQuantification` extension and modify the class method:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data SomeEdgeSet = forall c. EdgeSet c => SomeEdgeSet c

class Graph a where
  edges :: a -> SomeEdgeSet 

instance Graph Tree where
  edges tree = SomeEdgeSet DirectedEdgeSet
```

As you can tell, each one of your instances of `Graph` all return `SomeEdgeSet` when `edges` is used, but that `SomeEdgeSet` contains anything, as long as that thing is an instance of `EdgeSet`.

#### `TypeFamilies` solution

This is the solution I recommend. In general, for any `Graph`, you will only ever have *one* type of `Edges` it returns. Then, there is this cool feature with `TypeFamilies` where you can declare a type inside a class:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, UndecideableInstances #-}

class (EdgeSet (Edges a)) => Graph a where
  type Edges a
  edges :: a -> Edges a
```

Then, suppose that your representation of edges for `Graph Tree` is `DirectedEdgeSet`, your instance will look like:

```
class Graph Tree where
  type Edges Tree = DirectedEdgeSet -- `DirectedEdgeSet` is the type here
  edges tree = DirectedEdgeSet      -- `DirectedEdgeSet` is the constructor here
```

Comment: Nice approach. I note that the type families solution is not perfectly adherent to the OP question, since the OP typeclass `EdgeSet` may have methods, which instead might be unavailable on the type family. I'd be tempted to use `class (EdgeSet (ES a)) => Graph a where type ES a ; edges :: a -> ES a` and turn on undecidable instances. Or, alternatively `class Graph a where ... ; getDict :: Dict (EdgeSet (ES a))` possibly with a nice `default` implementation so that instances will not have to state `getDict = Dict` every time.

Comment: @chi I initially had the undecideable instances version typed up, but I thought I'd wait and see if OP really had methods in `EdgeSet`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifacation and solution suggestions. As @chi guessed, I actually have methods of the EdgeSet type. I edited to illustrate. Can you edit your answer?

Comment: By the way, I never had to dive into Haskell extensions. I don't want to do anything that isn't haskell-ideomatic! Perhaps my OO-mindset is misleading me. I would be open to redesigning my solution in a more functional style and would be happy for any tips and pointers

Comment: @Isund Many Haskell extensions are very idiomatic nowadays. While Haskell98 and 2010 are nice basic languages, many haskellers nowadays make use of many GHC extensions in everyday code. There are some extensions which are regarded as "bad(-dish)", though. `UndecidableInstances` is still OK-ish: the worst it can do, when misused, is to make the compiler loop forever. But, if the compiler terminates, the resulting program does not break any nice property of Haskell. (Unlike e.g. overlapping/incoherent instances which are evil, and make the code fragile.)

Comment: @Isund Updated!

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 5):

In `edges`, the type variable `c` is *universally quantified*. That means that `edges` must work for *all* types which are instances of `EdgeSet`. Your implementation fixes a concrete type and thus does not work for *all* `EdgeSet` instances.

To fix this, you can specify the concrete type of edge set that the instance uses via type families:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

data Tree = Tree
data DirectedEdgeSet = DirectedEdgeSet

class Graph a where
  type GraphEdgeSet a :: *
  edges :: a -> GraphEdgeSet a

instance Graph Tree where
  type GraphEdgeSet Tree = DirectedEdgeSet
  edges tree = DirectedEdgeSet
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and suggestion. However, my DirectedEdgeSet is more than just a type and also has methods. I didn't include it in the original post since I didn't know it mattered. Would you suggest another solution to my problem that is more haskell like perhaps? Or are there any other work-arounds?

Comment: Oh yes, and it's actually written in the error message that it's universally quantified `edges :: forall c. EdgeSet c => Tree -> c`. Yet difficult to catch for a beginners eye